# Composite Aggregation with sorted data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get grouped data with composite aggregation.

Grouping field is "fromNumber". I want to get grouped(by "fromNumber") call records descending(by "callStartStamp").

Let's say I have 400 records, and given these records;

1. fromNumber=0212 123....  callStartStamp="2020-09-09T08:14:38"
2. fromNumber=0312 312....  callStartStamp="2020-09-09T08:10:38"
3. fromNumber=0502 313....  callStartStamp="2020-09-10T08:10:38"

When I run the below code, I expect to get data in order 3, 1, 2 and so on.

When I give the bucket size 20, I can not get the 3. record, because it gets the data sorted ascending(by key). It returns 1, 2 .. and so on. Because 1. and 2. records has "fromNumber" starts with "02" and "03. The 3. records starts with "05".

So the turn(by ascending) doesn't come to 3. record to get in the grouped data(because of size 20).

If I give the bucket size 300, 3. data also comes because it reaches to data ascending(by key).

So I tried to order the data descending by "callStartStamp" before aggregation. But It does not work.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "firmId": {
              "value": 8525,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "callStartStamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": {
    "fromNumberAgg": {
      "composite": {
        "size":  20,
        "sources": [
          {
            "byFromNumber": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "fromNumber",
                "missing_bucket": false,
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "after": {
          "byFromNumber": ""
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 1000,
            "version": false,
            "seq_no_primary_term": false,
            "explain": false,
            "sort": [
              {
                "callStartStamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "lastCallStart": {
          "max": {
            "field": "callStartStamp"
          }
        },
        "sortByCallStart": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "lastCallStart": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "from": 0,
            "gap_policy": "SKIP"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```